# Uneven bevel width in Blender 2.82

Tags: error, bevel

I'm getting weird uneven bevel width then trying to use bevel tool (ctrl+B) on those 3 edges in the edit mode. Scale, rotation, and position are applied, everything is 1 1 1 in the item's transform.

[image: This 3 edges are selected]

[image: And this is the result of the beveling]

Never have this strange behavior in Maya, is it that Blender's bevel algorithm just can't work with this type of geometry?

Answer (score 0):

Normally Id suggest checking normals and non manifold geometry for anything causing trouble.
[image: attempted bevel]

However I did a little mockup and found that simply blender doesn't support it. I did hear stuff about miter options that might change this stuff in the future, but I recommend using the knife tool with cut through or a loop cut if you want more straight loops.

Comment: Thanks! Well, it's really time-consuming to do it with the knife, why they just can't copy the Maya's bevel behavior?)